# With all the short forms (abbreviations) , should we use only "an" as article?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

e.g. An MP(Member of Parliament) should be responsible for his own catchment area.

Is that correct ? or should I user "a" article instead of "an".

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

The indefinite article used before a letter of the alphabet, alone or starting an abbreviation or initialism, depends on the pronunciation of the letter. 'An' before a vowel sound, 'a' before a consonant sound. For the letter M we say 'em', which starts with a vowel sound, so we say or write 'an MP'.